# What are the packages in /configuration/ used for in my Eclipse directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I've recently installed the Eclipse IDE for Java on Linux. I noticed that there is a new directory: `/usr/lib/eclipse/configuration` and inside, there are some packages like:

```
configuration/
configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime
configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator
configuration/config.ini
configuration/org.eclipse.update
configuration/org.eclipse.osgi
```

And so on... So I'm wondering, what are these packages used for and how are they different from the ones in the plugins directory? Can I import them into my application? It is not clear to me how Eclipse uses the packages in the `configuration` directory. I've actually gone into a few of the package folders in there, and there are more subfolders that are named using integers. I have no idea what these are for.

Answer (score 1):

These files and directories are configuration information for Eclipse which is global to the complete installation rather than specific to a particular workspace. The contents includes things such as lists of plug-ins, and startup parameters.

The numbered folders in the org.eclipse.osgi directory contain temporary files that needed to be unpacked from plug-in jars. Eclipse manages these.

They are vital to Eclipse operation so they should just be left alone, You don't need to do anything with them.